# C - Is there a way to differentiate a unity, dozen or hundreds while reading a number on a file?

Tags: c, file

My program need to read i file that indicate if it have to enqueue a number, dequeue a number or finish the program.

I have a `.txt` file that looks like this:

```
E    10
E    2
E    300
D
D
D
E    40
E    50
T
```

So, `E` say "hey, you have enqueue something" (in first line is 10),
`D` say "hey, dequeue the guy at the head of the queue",
and `T` say "hey, dequeue everyone, free the memory, that's all"

I try using `getc` but it get every single character, the output is:

```
E

1
0
```

And with `fgets` i have the line, that's not what i want.

What i want is a way to the program understand the difference between 10(decimal), 2(unity), 300(hundreds). How can i get the `E` than jump the white space, then get `10` (and not `1` then `0`)? Is there a function to do this?

Obs: The file with inputs can't be changed, it has to be this way.

Comment: If you're designing a file format, define a grammar for it.

Comment: The file format can't be changed. I't has to be this way: `E (space) number`

Comment: I'd do it one character at a time. The math should be reasonably easy.

Comment: Alternately, you could get the whole line, use the first character to determine your actions, move the pointer past all the spaces, and use `atoi` or something similar to get the number that remains.

Comment: @FilipiMaciel You can still define a grammar for an existing file format. Once you have a grammar, writing a parser becomes relatively easy (you might even be able to generate a parser automatically then).

Comment: @MathieuK. I could't find a function to do this, so i'll try like you said, one character at a time. Thank you!

Comment: @EOF, hmmm, i'll check about that too. Thank you!

Comment: I hate to say it, but this could be relatively easily done with repeated calls to `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
char c;
while (fscanf(fp, " %c", &c) == 1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'E': {
            int n;
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) != 1) {
                input error; handle it
            }
            enqueue(n);
            break;
        }
        case 'D':
            dequeue();
            break;
        case 'T':
            destroy_queue();
            break;
        default:
            unknown command; handle error
    }
}
if (ferror(fp)) {
    input failed; handle error
}
```

Note that technically this will parse a superset of the file format you described. In particular, it doesn't care about line boundaries or formatting:

```
E1D

  D    E

2  E  3E
    4   D
     D
```

is perfectly acceptable and treated the same as

```
E   1
D
D
E   2
E   3
E   4
D
D
```

`fscanf` is used for all input. `" %c"` skips over any whitespace which may be present and then reads a single character. In particular, after the first line there will always be whitespace which we have to skip over: The `\n` at the end of the preceding line.

`"%d"` implicitly skips over any whitespace and reads an integer (in decimal format).