# Store sections of input in different variables

Tags: c

I need to read an input from user and store parts of it in different variables to use it later in a linked list that i'll sort.

The problem is: some operations need 4 arguments like Insertion, and others needs less like P (print) is just one ('P') and O (sort) needs 2 values.

Examples of inputs:

Insert: [I 43423 Julio 8] -> I for Insertion, 43423 is Value1, Julio is Name and 8 is Value2;

Sort: [O 1 2] -> O for Sorting, 1 for SelectionSort, 2 to sort the 'Name' field;

Print: [P] -> P for Print;

I've tried using scanf expecting 4 arguments ("%s %s %s %s"), making a linked list just for the input and messing with vectors, none have worked because of the number of arguments.

```
int main() {
    int ra, nota;
    char oper, nome[51];
    scanf("%c %d %s %d", &oper, &ra, nome, &nota);
    printf("%s\n", oper);
    printf("%d\n", ra);
    printf("%s\n", nome);
    printf("%d\n", nota);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above works for the Insertion operation, but when I try to print (P) the code gives an error because it was expecting 4 arguments.

Comment: Sorry, it is C.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666221/1848654 and can be solved the same way (repeated calls to `scanf`).

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the answer, i'll look the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive from the standard input varying numbers of values, you have to use several `scanf` statements. This is the general code:

```
int a, b, c, d;

if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4) /* 4 items supplied */
    . . . 
else if (scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) { /* 3 supplied */
    d = 0; /* zero out an unused value */
    . . .
}
else if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2) { /* 2 supplied */
    c = d = 0; /* zero out an unused value */
    . . .
}
else if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) { /* 1 supplied */
    b = c = d = 0; /* zero out an unused value */
    . . .
}
else
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad input");
```

Note we start from the case with the greatest number of items. Then we work our way down. If we had started from the fewest number, then that case would test true even if more arguments were actually supplied.

Comment: That only works if all the arguments are numbers (and none of the following input items start with a number). That's not the case with OP's problem.

Comment: First thanks for the answer! @melpomene, I think that will work if I adapt it to my needs, gonna try.

Comment: That doesn't work, if the first if is true the program runs like mine, but if it tries to go to the else it still waits for the 4th input.